# Java - check to see if user entered blank value is failing

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and am playing around with some console apps. I'm trying to validate user input, and prompt the user to enter another value if they enter something wrong. Whenever I enter an "empty" value, the program hangs, and when I stop it, it spits out all of the errors. How can I actually check for empty?

example:

```
do{
            //prompt user for word
            System.out.print("\nType \"quit\" to exit \n");
            System.out.print("Enter a single word with no spaces: ");

            //check to make sure user entered a valid string
            if (in.hasNext()){
                strWord = in.next();
                int nWordLength = strWord.length();
                if(nWordLength > 0 && !strWord.isEmpty()){ 
                  //do a whole bunch of stuff
                  // removed for brevity
                }else{
                //alert user of invalid entry
                System.out.println("Not a valid word.");
            }else{
            //alert user of invalid entry
            System.out.println("Not a valid word.");
        }
}while (!strWord.equals("quit")); //end if user enters quit

System.out.println("You are now done with the program");
```

After I kill my program because it hangs, I get output like the below...

Type "quit" to exit
Enter a single word with no spaces: Not a valid word.

Type "quit" to exit 
Enter a single word with no spaces: Not a valid word.

Type "quit" to exit
Enter a single word with no spaces: Not a valid word.

Type "quit" to exit

Process finished with exit code -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to simplify your code

```
     boolean isValidInput = false;
  do{
    //check to make sure user entered a valid string
    strWord = in.nextLine();

    if(!(strWord.isEmpty()) && !(Character.isWhiteSpace(strWord.charAt(0))))
    {
        isValidInput = true;
        //whatever goes here
    } 
    else
       System.out.println("incorrect word entered");

    }while(!isValidInput);
```

Comment: This seems to work for strings, is there a way to make this work for ints?

Comment: if it is a `Scanner` then `nextInt()` , `nextDouble()` etc will  be there to rescue you

Comment: @user797963 as litttle child pointed out you would use the corresponding method to whichever kind of input you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `in` is a `Scanner` ?

I think the problem is your code never sees the input from the user.

What if you replace all your calls to `hasNext()` and `next()` with `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()` which buffer and wait for the user to hit enter?